# Confusions regarding the metatheory

Tags: logic, set-theory, meta-math

Kunen's *Set Theory* (2011) raised some uncomfortable questions regarding my understanding of the metatheory. Let me present my questions in in terms of two perspectives, in both of which we use $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as the working example.

**Perspective 1. The intuitive construction.** We take metatheoretic notions such as structural induction on proof trees and inductive definition of well-formed formulas etc. as given. We also take basic facts about how models behave as given. We then syntactically prove as many $\varphi$s such that $\vdash_\mathsf{ZFC} \varphi$ as we can. Then, we observe that the model-theoretic interpretations of these can simulate the aforementioned basic metatheoretic assumptions (induction, facts about models, etc.). This is the justification that our metatheory is in fact $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

**Perspective 2. The big picture.** Now, instead of following the process, we try to elucidate what *precisely* we are dealing with all at once. To preserve simplicity, I will assume Platonism (although you are more than welcome to add another perspective, like formalism, in your answer; that would be very interesting). So, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is true in the real world; this is our metatheory. In fact, the metatheory is all there is. In it, we can *represent* things like strings, formulas, inference rules, the relations $\vdash$, $\vDash$, models etc.

Now comes my problem. I don't know how to picture in what way our "really true" $\mathsf{ZFC}$ represents (or, more suggestively, *simulates*) things like sequents, models, etc. What kind of objects *precisely* am I dealing with here? Metatheoretic sentences? I currently have no idea.

The main motivation for finding this out is that if I have a more solid grasp of what's actually going on when working in the metatheory, I might be able to work in it more confidently. Thank you for all the help. :)

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/426939/2126

Comment: Your perspective 2 seems like a category error to me. Philosophical positions like Platonism are actually irrelevant in formalised mathematics.

Comment: A bit of formalist perspective you might find helpful: you're not necessarily dealing with any objects at all.

Comment: Developing models of a mathematical theory, like e.g. $\mathsf {ZFC}$ using a meta-theory that is a different version of set theory is not IMO a way to add some "philosophical gist" to our understanding of what *sets* are "in the real world". It is a way to understand the properties of the formal theory under observation, in terms of consistency structure of models (if any) and so on.

Comment: @RobArthan Are they? I think that it varies from person to person. I personally find it much easier to be confident in my work if I have some underlying idea of precisely what is going on in the metatheory. Of course, many won't care at all and just play Russell's "game on paper."